# Converting hmmer --tblout to pandas dataframe

Tags: hmmer, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to convert a hmmer output to a pandas dataframe? I am also unsure how to load a hmmer tblout table into python via the Bio module. I believe you can call a hmmer format with SeqIO.parse or SeqIO.search. How can you convert the table to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: This question was answered on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012615/convert-a-hmmer-tblout-output-to-a-pandas-dataframe/62021471#62021471

Comment: It is rude to cross-post on multiple forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The manual](http://eddylab.org/software/hmmer3/3.1b2/Userguide.pdf) says fields in a tabular output file are space-delimited. It should be fairly straightforward to load a space-delimited file in pandas.

From the manual:

> `--tblout <f>` Save a simple tabular (space-delimited) file summarizing the per-target output, with one data line per homologous target model found.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4581)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, @Michael. I've added an excerpt from the manual.

Comment: Thanks @RamRS ... much better :-)

Comment: This question was answered on StackOverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012615/convert-a-hmmer-tblout-output-to-a-pandas-dataframe/62021471#62021471